# etree.fromstring(response.text.encode('utf-8'), parser=etree.XMLParser(huge_tree=self.huge_tree))

Tags: python-3.x

All,

I have written a script to inset data into a sharepoint list using pyton-shareplum. The code is as below.

```
from shareplum import Site
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
import pandas as pd
import datetime

#***********************Login into SharePoint Site***************************#
auth = HttpNtlmAuth('xxxx', 'xxxxx')
site = Site('https://x.x.com/sites/UnityI/xx', auth=auth,huge_tree=True)

sp_list = site.List('Investment Request')
approved_data = sp_list.GetListItems(viewname='All Condensed',query=None)
df = pd.DataFrame(approved_data)


# ***********************Read List2 Data - UnApproved List********************#

sp_list = site.List('Investment Request UnApproved')
unapproved_data = sp_list.GetListItems(viewname='All Unapproved Projects',query=None)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(unapproved_data)

#
# #*****************Concatenate - Approved & UnApproved List********************#
#
df2 = pd.concat([df,df1], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
CombinedData = pd.DataFrame(df2)


CombinedData_3Columns = pd.DataFrame(CombinedData, columns=['ID','Project Name Title','Project Type','Client','Approval','Approval Date','Est Cost'])

CombinedData_3Columns = CombinedData_3Columns.astype(str)

new_list = site.List('IRC Combined Data')
fields = ['ID']
dev_ids =  [row['ID'] for row in new_list.GetListItems(fields=fields)]
new_list.UpdateListItems(dev_ids, 'Delete')

new_list = site.List('IRC Combined ClarityID')
my_data=data= approved_data_todict
new_list.UpdateListItems(data=my_data, kind='New')
```

When I try to load data, I'm getting below the error message.

> File "C:/PyCharm/CombinedData.py", line 63, in 
>       new_list.UpdateListItems(data=my_data, kind='New')   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\shareplum\shareplum.py", line 660, in
>   UpdateListItems
>       envelope = etree.fromstring(response.text.encode('utf-8'), parser=etree.XMLParser(huge_tree=self.huge_tree))   File
>   "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 3236, in lxml.etree.fromstring   File
>   "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1876, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument
>   File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1764, in lxml.etree._parseDoc   File
>   "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1127, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc 
>   File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 601, in
>   lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc   File
>   "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 711, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
>   File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 640, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
>   File "", line 11 lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: expected '>', line
>   11, column 112

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6wAO.png)

Comment: Despite non-descript title, your code, and your image-of-code, the error says that your XML is bad.

Comment: any idea how to rectify?

Comment: is this causing because of double/single quotes in the string?